# Vue and Blazor for frontend

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, blazor

we have a project that we need to create a website for the university. The whole desin and vue part is done. But there was a misunderstanding and lack of communication with our teacher and he wants us to create the admin panel with .NET Blazor. For example we have announcements part in our website and we need to fill that part with the data coming from admin panel that had created with Blazor. But is it possible? Can I run both of the projects on same browser and same port_ Thank you for your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For development mode: You can run your Vue frontend (eg) at port 4200, You backend runs at 5050 (eg). Then you can create a proxy so you can request your Frontend to your API. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy
- For Prod mode: You build your frontend to a dist folder then you copy the output to the wwwroot of your backend app. Now your front end will be a part of your API. Since your blazor app is unchanged, they can work together See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to help ;)